# What's the sample space for a conditional expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Define a probability space $(\Omega,\cal F,\Bbb P)$ and a $\cal F$ measurable random variable $X$, the conditional expectation given a sub $\sigma$-algebra $\cal F_0 \subseteq \cal F$ is a random variable $X_0=\Bbb E(X|\cal F_0)$ satisfying the following two conditions:

1. $X_0$ is $\cal F_0$ measurable.
2. For any $E\in \cal F_0$, it holds that $\int_E {X} d\Bbb P =\int_E {X_0} d\Bbb P$.

My confusion is that, since $X_0$ is a random variable, **it must be a function defined on a sample space, then what is the sample space** for $X_0$? Further the sample space must be equipped with a $\sigma$-algebra to form a measurable space, so what is the $\sigma$-algebra? Since $X_0$ is $\cal F_0$ measurable, so I suppose the $\sigma$-algebra associated with the sample space is $\cal F_0$?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, assuming that $X_0\colon F_0 \to \mathbf{R}$ is sensible.  Stronger assumptions can make the definition vacuous.

Comment: Conditional expectation $X_0 \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is random variable defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,\cal F,\Bbb P)$ as random variable $X$.

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic Thank you for the reply! But I am still confused. If the sample space is still $\Omega$, how does $X_0$ map elements of $\Omega$ to $\Bbb{R}$? For example, suppose $\Omega$ is the outcome of a dice, i.e. $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and $X(\omega) = \omega$ for any $\omega \in \Omega$. If $\cal F_0$ $=\{\emptyset,\Omega, A,A^C \}$ where $A=\{1,3,5\}$, then how $X_0$ should look like?

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic $X(\omega)=\omega$ for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: Conditional expectation is $X_0(\omega)=3$ for $\omega \in \{1,3,5\}$ and $1$ for $\omega \in \{2,4,6\}$.

Comment: I am sorry, there was a typo in my previous comment, $X_0(\omega)=4$ for $\omega \in \{2,4,6\}$.

Comment: You can check for yourself that this function satisfies the conditions 1 and 2 from your own definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: @nomen Spreading random unfounded opinions on a subject that one obviously does not master should be avoided.

Comment: @Did: If $X$ is $F_0$ measurable and $G_0$ is coarser than $F_0$, $X$ need not be $G_0$ measurable.  What's the problem?

Comment: @nomen To begin with, $X_0$ is not defined on $F_0$.

Comment: @Did:  But $F_0$ induces the most parsimonious sample space for the events in $F_0$, as the union of elements of $F_0$.  As far as I can tell, this is a minor and natural abuse of notation.

Comment: @nomen ?? The union of the events in $F_0$ is equal to the union of the events in any sigma-algebra on the sample space $\Omega$, that is, equal to $\Omega$ itself. This simple remark shows that the notion of "union of the elements of a sigma-algebra" is rather empty (and it is odd that you see fit to invoke it).